# How do I write a "distinct on" finder method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, distinct

I'm using RoR 5.0.1 with PostGres 9.5.  I have the following query that gets distinct records from a specific table (represented by a corresponding model) based on a date

```
select distinct on (crypto_currency_id) t.* 
from crypto_prices t 
order by crypto_currency_id, last_updated desc;
```

My model name is CryptoPrice, but I'm unclear how to convert the above into a finder method.  This

```
CryptoPrice.distinct.pluck(:crypto_currency_id)
```

doesn't do the same thing, as I discovered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There isn't Rails built-in method for Postgres `DISTINCT ON` statement. It seems like you could use `DISTINCT ON` in your select:

```
CryptoPrice.select('DISTINCT ON (crypto_currency_id) *')
           .order(:crypto_currency_id, last_updated: :desc)
```

This will produce exactly the same query as in your instance.